# Scons: one big SContruct for all vs many small ones

Tags: build, scons

I am moving Code::Blocks projects to SCons. I have a source tree with the following structure:

```
trunk
    lib1
    lib2
    libn
    app1
    app2
    appn
```

This is my first time with Scons and I am trying to figure out what would be better - to have many small SConscripts in each app and lib folder or one big SContruct under the trunk with sections describing sources, switches and pre/post build commands for each project.

I personally prefer dealing with one file but I'd like to hear the opinion of the people experienced with SCons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of individual `SConscript` files is that filenames within each one are relative to the directory in which the `SConscript` file resides. So creating a list of filenames for a build target becomes less verbose.

On the other hand, targets that need to be shared among different `SConscript` files sometimes end up needing a lot of `Export()`-ing and `Import()`-ing of symbols to communicate with each other.

It looks like your apps and libraries are pretty well separated. In your case, I would start with creating multiple `SConscript` files in each major directory. It's generally easier to combine them later, than to separate them later.

Comment: I just think how can I keep dozens of SConscript files in a consistent format so that I don't end up with each SConscript building in it's own, bit different way.

Comment: That argument doesn't make sense, because you probably already do that for your many different source code files. SConscript files are Python source code. It's not that hard to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

Would you make your real project organized in one big file or many small files? Sure, it may be easier to do some things if everything is all in one file, but for organization, multiple files can sometimes be easier.

You may want to try doing something like having global settings in your main trunk-located SConstruct file (so stuff like your warning and optimization flags), and then import that into your SConscript files which take care of target-specific details.